# Why is this login program can login when i correct putting the username and password just at the first time?

Tags: python

So, I tried to make a simple login program with python. And get stuck with the else condition thing, when the username and password don't match, I want to make it start all over again which is the Username input and Password input. Then I just wrote `login()` in else block. I can login when I put the correct username and password at the first try. But when I am wrong once, then input the correct username and password, it just goes back to the `login()` function.
 I'm new with `python`, so I think making a simple login is a good exercise for "if else condition". Sorry for my bad english, thank you.

```
admin = "admin"
key = "admin"

def login():
    access = False
    while access == False:
        username = input("Username : ")
        password = input("Password : ")
        if username == admin and password == key:
            access = True
            print("Welcome admin")
        else:
            login()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the while loop and recursion combined. The first time you enter the wrong inputs, the `login()` is called for a second time. And you enter the correct inputs now. So it sets access to `True` and prints `Welcome admin` and returns. But when it returns, the value of access now is False, hence it continues looping. You can fix this by either replacing the `while` with an `if` statement, or by removing recursion.

By replacing `while` with `if`:

```py
admin = "admin"
key = "admin"

def login():
    access = False
    if not access:
        username = input("Username : ")
        password = input("Password : ")
        if username == admin and password == key:
            access = True
            print("Welcome admin")
        else:
            login()
```

Removing recursion:

```py
admin = "admin"
key = "admin"

def login():
    access = False
    while not access:
        username = input("Username : ")
        password = input("Password : ")
        if username == admin and password == key:
            access = True
            print("Welcome admin")
```

This method is probably preferred because recursion is not really needed here.

Comment: Thankyou dude i tried put "access = True" in the else condition. Then it works properly. Can you explain to me how is it works? .______.

Comment: @Resh I'm assuming that you meant that you put `access = True` __inside__ the `else` block. Assume the first input entered is wrong, it goes into the `login()` function again, and also sets `access` as `True` in the outer function. And you enter the correct input the second time. So, inside the inner function, the if condition is true, it sets `access` as `True` and returns. Now it is in the outer function, where `access` is already `True`. Since `access` is already `True`, the `while` loop condition returns `False` and exits. (continued)

Comment: @Resh(cont) The thing you have to understand is that, every time `login()` calls itself, the new function instance has its own set of variables, like `access`. The values are not shared between the function calls. As I've mentioned in my answer, recursion is not needed here. And please note that the terminology I've used, inner and outer functions, are not accurate. That is just for your understanding

Answer (score 0):

This code will work as you wanted it to:

```
admin = "admin"
key = "admin"


def login():
    access = False
    if access is False:
        username = input("Username : ")
        password = input("Password : ")
        if username == admin and password == key:
            access = True
            print("welcome admin")
        else:
            login()


login()
```